# HTTP Post method, maximum bytes/data we can submit?

Tags: java, http, post, httpconnection

I am trying to use HTTP Post to call a URL, I want know the limit of bytes i can write through post method. Is there a limit for the data you can send through HTTP Post method?

I am using `HTTPUrlConnection` api java for posting data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's usually no limit from the client side, the limit is set on the server side. For example Apache Tomcat uses maxPostSize, which is defaulted to 2M.

Comment: where can i find this option in apache tomcat?

Comment: It's set in your server.xml file. See here for the HTTP connector, http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html